# Filter a Dataframe with another Dataframe to extract Certain Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filtering

I have two csv files.

- One has minutely data
- Other has hourly
- Both having same headers

I want to run the hourly dataframe over the minutely dataframe to extract out certain entries with criteria:

1. The filter DF (hourly DF) needs to match Temporally with the file it is
   searching through Ie values in minutely DF at mm/dd/yyyy 9:00 to
   mm/dd/yyyy 9:59 use the values at mm/dd/yyyy 9:00 in hourly DF as
   the search criteria.
2. The filter criteria uses 3 variable columns +- certain range for each.
3. The selected data satisfying the filter is extracted to another dataframe to be saved later as a csv

This sounds like something someone has to have done before! I myself know a bit of pandas but only did simple filters for dataframes.

Df1 minutely data

```
    Date        pressure      temperature           density
9/12/2014 9:00  177.859887      4.574663842         1028.477
9/12/2014 9:01  214.3598333     4.397781667         1028.66
9/12/2014 9:02  264.5863333     4.208137222         1028.905
9/12/2014 10:00 314.3161111     4.1242              1029.143
9/12/2014 10:01 363.8005587     4.02983352          1029.377
```

DF2 Hourly data

```
    Date          pressure    temperature          density
9/12/2014 9:00     170            4.0                1028
9/12/2014 10:00    368            4.2                1028.5
```

With example above the three variables will be pressure, temperature and density. For simplicity sake let's try to extract the first and fifth row in the DF1 so our example search criteria

- pressure +- 8
- Temp +-.6
- density +- 1

To make
DF3 filtered data

```
 Date             pressure          temperature         density
9/12/2014 9:00   177.859887         4.574663842         1028.477
9/12/2014 10:01  363.8005587        4.02983352          1029.377
```

I don't exactly know how to approach this. Would it be for loops? I do not know where exactly to look to make something elegant and nicely well made.

```
    For idx in DF
    
    For idx2 in DF2
    
    if idx2 == date in idx and variable 1 +- range and variable 2 +- range and variable 3 +- range
    
    print idx
    
    when datetime (only hourly resolution) in idx ≠ datetime in idx2; idx +1
```

Comment: Have you tried join? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 0):

1. import your sample data into df1 and df2
2. define index that is the timestamp of the observation
3. upsample hourly data to every minute
4. join upsampled date to minute frequency data to create df3
5. you can now compare and contrast as much as you want as it's all in one data frame

```
data = '''Date          pressure    temperature          density
9/12/2014 9:00     170            4.0                1028
9/12/2014 10:00    368            4.2                1028.5'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
data='''Date        pressure      temperature           density
9/12/2014 9:00  177.859887      4.574663842         1028.477
9/12/2014 9:01  214.3598333     4.397781667         1028.66
9/12/2014 9:02  264.5863333     4.208137222         1028.905
9/12/2014 10:00  314.3161111     4.1242              1029.143
9/12/2014 10:01  363.8005587     4.02983352          1029.377'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])

df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", utc=True)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", utc=True)
df3 = df1.join(df2.resample("1min").pad(), rsuffix="_hourly")
df3
```